# Parse JSON encoded data in Vue Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am passing a `json encoded` data to my `Vue component` as a `prop`, when I am printing the whole prop variable then it is showing that the data has successfully received, but I am not able to parse the data.

### profile.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <my-profile user-details="{{ json_encode($userDetails) }}"></my-profile>

@endsection
```

### MyProfile.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content">
            <div class="col-md-3" id="profile-image">
                <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/paris.jpg" alt="Profile Image">
            </div>            
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>{{userDetails}}</p>
                <p> Name:  {{ userDetails.first_name }} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
#profile-image {
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
props: ["userDetails"]
}
</script>
```

### Output

```
    {"user_id":2,"first_name":"Shan","last_name":"Biswas","email":"shanpro.2015@gmail.com","phone":"9508168983","created_at":"2019-05-03 05:43:17","updated_at":"2019-05-03 05:43:17"}

    Name:
```

Comment: What you tried for parse data? & where you want this parsed data, show unworkable code

Comment: Did you try to use `json_decode()` to get your data in your Vue template ?

Comment: The props `userDetails` is receiving as an string, I have to convert it using JSON.stringfy(). I am not able to find out how to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the value to the component as dynamic and not static.
So change your blade file to:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <!-- see the colon in front of the props, that is a shortcut for v-bind:prop-name -->
    <my-profile :user-details="{{ json_encode($userDetails) }}"></my-profile>

@endsection
```

Otherwise are all values passed to the component as a simple string.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```html
<my-profile user-details="{{ json_encode($userDetails) }}"></my-profile>
```

with this:

```html
<my-profile user-details='@json($userDetails)'></my-profile>
// Pay attention to single quotes instead of double
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Nope, not working.

`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "userDetails". Expected Object, got String with value "{"first_name":"Shan","last_name":"Biswas"}".

found in

---> <MyProfile> at resources/js/components/MyProfile.vue`

Answer (score 0):

Update profile.blade.php to following!

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <my-profile user-details="{{ $userDetails }}"></my-profile>

@endsection
```